# Using compression screw as air engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, compressed-air

Can a screw such as the one below be used as an air engine in pressure range between 700 kPa and 2500 kPa 
on other words Can I reverse compression process with a screw to work as air engine

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Instead of "low pressure," give us the range of pressure you expect or require in your application. Instead of "used as an air engine," give us a description of the engine that is complete enough for an expert to understand exactly what you're proposing. You could describe the engine with a schematic, with an analogy or in some other way, as long as you clearly communicate what problem you're trying to solve. More details about the screw wouldn't hurt, either; material, dimensions, etc.

Comment: I think this is asking is a screw compressor can be used as pneumatic motor. The answer is no.

Comment: @ Chris Johns Can you explain Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some processes are reversible, but this one isn't.  When a compressor compresses a fluid, it can do so via increasing the stream velocity (such as a piston or a rotor), or it can do by increasing the pressure/density from direct compression (such as a [peristaltic pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump)).  The first is reversible - the high stream velocity can push back on the solid object, slowing down, and transferring momentum back into a shaft.  The second is irreversible - the high pressure fluid can't compress the in-compressible solid and get it to move preferentially in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine an Archimedes screw ( figure) being effective moving air/ gas. If you want to get work out of high pressure air , A reciprocal machine, ie a "steam" engine would be about the only effective mechanism.